# Can I use mix of GSuite and my own server to send emails?

Tags: email, dns, google-workspace

I am hosting my email address, for example, arvind@mydomain.com on Gsuite.

How do I add more addresses in my server such as abc@mydomain.com and use my own server, such as my website to send emails to this user. I created abc@mydomain.com using WHM/cpanel for the domain. I am able to send email from this address but they end in spam folder. Also I am not able to send emails to this address.

I have added Google's server to MX entries and my own server such as mail.mydomain.com. However if I try to send email to abc@mydomain.com it fails with "Address not found".

How can I fix it? I am able to edit DNS entries if required to.

Comment: Use only Gsuite, both for sending and receiving, and create as many accounts as you need there.

Comment: I don't want to add them to Gsuite since I have to pay for every new account. I already have to a good VPS on Linode so I don't want to pay separately for hosting emails. So I think I should stop using Gsuite and continue with my own VPS, right?

Comment: Technically, you should probably keep your email accounts in one place, otherwise it becomes a mess. Personally, I don't think you should host your own email unless you know really well what you are doing (at least if you want them confidently delivered/received; if it is for learning purposes, sure, go ahead)